# Switching between JPanels

Tags: java, arraylist, jframe, jpanel, visible

I'm trying to make a game. There's several different screens in the game such as a main menu, and the actual game screen. Each of these is a separate jpanel extension. I have added each of them to my JFrame which is a class called Game. In my game class I have the following methods

```
public void addPanel( JPanel p ) {
    panels.add( p ); // An array of all the different panels I need
    this.getContentPane().add( p );
}

public void switchToPanel( JPanel p ) {
    for ( JPanel somePanel : panels ) {
        somePanel.setVisible( false );
    }

    p.setVisible( true );
    repaint();
}
```

The point of this is that I have many different panels and when I need to show a particular one, such as a menu screen, I call switchToPanel( myPanel ). Basically just hiding every panel and then unhiding the one that I need to see. Only problem is that these panels aren't showing up when I switch to them. The only one that will ever show up is the panel that I added last. In Objective C I use this technique for switching between views all the time and I've never had any problems. Is this kind of thing not allowed in java?

Edit: now I am calling repaint() after switching, but it's still not working

Comment: havent touched these in a while but i think you need to be painting/repainting the frame if you want to see it.

Answer (score 9):

You can do a number of different things to achieve the same effect.

The first suggestion I'd make is use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) ([How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)) as this is what it was designed to do.

The other would be to use a [JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) ([How to use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html))

Comment: yeah i thought cardLayout was the way to go.

Comment: @SeanF It's designed to do what you want, why reinvent the wheel (I'm to lazy now days ;))

Comment: I figured it out actually, for some reason I have to call pack() each time I add a jpanel to my frame. I can't just add them all and then call pack(), I have to call it once after each panel is added. Weird!

Comment: @ChristianDaley Be careful with `pack()`. If the size of the content changes, the size of the frame will change.  This may not be the effect you want. Better to use `invalidate()` and `repaint()` ... or `CardLayout` which would be a better solution ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but all the jpanels I add are initialized with the same width and height as my main jframe, and the width and height don't change.

Answer (score 4):

If you are making a game, you make it in a separate thread different from the `EDT`. Most games show different screens by not changing panels but they use a single panel, on which they render according to `GameState`.

Here's an example.

```
public class MyGame extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public static enum GameState {
        MENU, INTRO, LEVELS, END, TITLES
    }

    GameState state = GameState.MENU;

    public MyGame(){
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        // Initialize the resources
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void update(long elapsedTime){
        switch (state){
            case MENU:
                // Show the menu
                break;
            ....
        }
    }

    private void GameLoop(){
        // Game Loop goes here
    }

    public void run(){
        GameLoop();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        // switch and draw your game
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("MyGame");
        f.setSize(640, 480);
        f.add(new MyGame());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

}

If one state ie., a menu completed, change the `state` variable. And first learn using a `GameEngine` before you make it on your own.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to switch between two panels add those panels into another JPanel and use cardLayout. Then, before adding a `JPanel` remove the current one. Like this:

```
parentPanel.removeAll();
parentPanel.repaint();
parentPanel.revalidate();

parentPanel.add(childPanel1);
parentPanel.repaint();
parentPanel.revalidate();
```

Likewise do the same thing for other child panels.

Answer (score 0):

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Test");
        jFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(jFrame.getOwner());
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        var jPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());


        jFrame.add(jPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        jFrame.add(new JButton("Switch") {
            {
                addActionListener(e -> {
                    b.set(!b.get());

                    jPanel.removeAll();
                    jPanel.repaint();
                    jPanel.revalidate();

                    jPanel.add(b.get() ? new JPanel() {
                        @Override
                        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                            setBackground(Color.RED);
                            super.paintComponent(g);
                        }
                    } : new JPanel() {
                        @Override
                        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            super.paintComponent(g);
                        }
                    });
                    jPanel.repaint();
                    jPanel.revalidate();

                });
            }
        }, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).